# How to create links in SharePoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have a C# script that is setting up SharePoint for me just the way I need it. One of the things I need it to do is to create various links in the Top link bar and the Quick launch menu. I can't seem to find anything explaining how to do this. I'm assuming it's possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Took some tricky googling, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427791.aspx) page goes over how to do exactly what I needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427791.aspx